Implementación de Rastreo de Pedidos en Nuestra Tienda Online
¡Hola a todos!
Estamos en el proceso de implementar un sistema de rastreo de pedidos en nuestra tienda online y nos encontramos con algunos desafíos que necesitamos abordar. Queremos asegurarnos de capturar automáticamente la ubicación tanto del restaurante como del cliente al realizar un pedido, y estamos buscando orientación sobre cómo lograrlo de la manera más efectiva y eficiente posible.
Desafíos que Enfrentamos:
Captura Automática de Ubicación del Restaurante: Queremos que la ubicación del restaurante se guarde en nuestra base de datos automáticamente al crear un nuevo restaurante en nuestra plataforma. ¿Cómo podemos implementar este proceso de captura automática de ubicación en segundo plano sin depender de que el restaurante proporcione manualmente su ubicación?
Captura Automática de Ubicación del Cliente: También queremos capturar automáticamente la ubicación del cliente al realizar un pedido en nuestra tienda online. ¿Cuáles son las mejores prácticas y tecnologías que podemos utilizar para obtener la ubicación del cliente de manera precisa y sin requerir acciones adicionales por parte del usuario?
Almacenamiento y Gestión de Datos: Una vez que obtengamos la ubicación del restaurante y del cliente, necesitamos almacenar esta información de manera adecuada en nuestra base de datos y vincularla correctamente con cada pedido. ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de organizar y estructurar nuestros datos para facilitar el rastreo de pedidos y la generación de informes?
Generación de Mapas de Rutas: Finalmente, queremos poder generar mapas de rutas para los pedidos asociados a cada restaurante desde el área de trabajo de ese restaurante en nuestra plataforma. ¿Qué herramientas o tecnologías podemos utilizar para crear estos mapas de manera eficiente y asegurarnos de que cada restaurante solo tenga acceso a la información de rastreo de sus propios pedidos?
¿Cómo Pueden Ayudarnos?
Estamos buscando orientación, consejos y mejores prácticas de la comunidad sobre cómo abordar estos desafíos y llevar a cabo con éxito la implementación de nuestro sistema de rastreo de pedidos. Cualquier sugerencia, experiencia o recurso que puedan compartir será de gran ayuda para nosotros.
¡Agradecemos de antemano su colaboración y apoyo en este emocionante proyecto!
Saludos cordiales,
asta ahora, hemos intentado utilizar diversas API de geolocalización para capturar automáticamente la ubicación del restaurante al crearlo en nuestra plataforma, así como la ubicación del cliente al realizar un pedido. Sin embargo, hemos enfrentado dificultades para lograr que este proceso funcione sin intervención manual. Además, hemos investigado la integración de la API de geolocalización en el lado del cliente para capturar la ubicación del cliente, pero hemos tenido dificultades para implementar esta funcionalidad de manera fluida. En cuanto al almacenamiento de datos, estamos trabajando en el diseño de nuestra base de datos para almacenar la ubicación del restaurante

y cual es la pregunta, el codigo, el error ???

te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

No es posible, tanto restaurant como cliente deben asignar su dirección.

@Yussef para una venta clandestina solo necesitas una direccion y es la del cliente ... de donde sale el producto y en que momento inicia el tracking de llegada de este es lo de menos XD

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
